# Powershell Export-CSV formatting

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

I'm exporting data from multiple paths from our network drives. If a document is older than a certain date, I export it to a CSV file. But when I open up Excel, theres no formatting. Everything is all jammed up in the "A" column. I would like the "Name" to be in column A, "LastWriteTime" to be in column B, etc.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($path in $SharedFolder)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateLimit} | 
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, Length, DirectoryName |
    Export-Csv -Path $HOME\Desktop\ExcelDoc.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the delimiter to the system default delimiter should take care of this. 
You can do this by adding -Delimiter to your command with the character specified.

For example: -Delimiter ';'